# webpack-dev-server 4.0.0 how to set stats?

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I've just upgraded webpack-dev-server to version 4.0.0 and my webpack.config.js devServer forgot how to handle "stats" option. Has it been removed somewhere else?

Error I get:

```
Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
```

[image: stats error]

Comment: Did you read the [migration guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but you can change stats option to:

```
devServer: {
    ...
    devMiddleware: {
        stats: options.stats,
    },
},
```

Related to [How to use the new Webpack devServer configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328035/how-to-use-the-new-webpack-devserver-configuration)